# Numy 2D image array how to apply formula to only pixels that satisfy a condition?

Tags: python, loops, sum, list-comprehension, vectorization

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def isblack(rgb):
    return (rgb[0]==0) and (rgb[1]==0) and (rgb[2]==0)

a = Image.open('image1.jpg')
a = np.array(a) # RGB image
[h,w,chan] = np.shape(a)
filtsz = 9
# comparing subimage with a[50:59,60:69] and a[100:119,120:129], for example
srcTop = 50
srcLeft = 60
dstTop = 100
dstLeft = 120 

ssd = 0 # sumOfSquareDifference
for i in range(filtsz):
  for j in range(filtsz):
    if not isblack(a[dstTop+i,dstLeft+j,:]):
      ssd += sum((a[dstTop+i, dstLeft+j] - a[srcTop+i, srcLeft+j])**2)
print(ssd)
```

The naive implementation is to loop over all pixel that satisfy the condition, then compute.
However, this is very slow.

How can I make it faster? I'm looking for a way that use indexing. For example, something that has the following pseudo code:

```
selected = [not isblack(pixel) for pixel in image] # 2D array contains 0 if black, 1 if not black
diff = [(a[pixel] - b[pixel])**2 for pixel in a] # 2D array contains the square difference at each pixel
ssd = sum(diff * selected) # sum only positions that satisfy the condition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = Image.open("image/image1.jpg")
filtsz = 100 # increase from 9 to 100 for display purpose
srcTop = 50
srcLeft = 60
dstTop = 100
dstLeft = 120
npimg = np.array(img)
# indexing
subimg_src = npimg[srcTop:srcTop+filtsz,srcLeft:srcLeft+filtsz,:] 
subimg_dst = npimg[dstTop:dstTop+filtsz,dstLeft:dstLeft+filtsz,:]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].imshow(subimg_src)
ax[1].imshow(subimg_dst)
```

[image]

```
# channel axis - 2
# ~: negation operator
# keepdims: set True for broadcasting
selected = ~np.any(subimg_dst,axis=2,keepdims=True) 
ssd = np.sum((subimg_src-subimg_dst)**2*selected)
print(ssd)
```

Example image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I notice that your "selected = ..." line only works with my isblack() function. Is there any way to make this more generic?

Comment: as long as your condition is pixelwise, it is equivalent to select_RGB = np.array([0,0,0]) # replace with your customized values selected = np.all(subimg_dst==select_RGB[None,None,:],axis=2,keepdims=True)

Comment: Yes but what if instead of comparing with a specific value, I need to evaluate a function? Still pixelwise, of course

Comment: I think this stopped working in newer version of Python :\ I keep getting deprecated error on operator "=="

Comment: That is probably not due to a newer python version though, "==" is interpreted by numpy as an elementwise comparison operator, so I guess something is incompatible between the two arrays you are comparing with, for example the shapes cannot be broadcasted or the data types are different (str vs float)